# DocuSign for Dynamics CRM - Unexpected exception from plug-in on "Get Signatures"

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi

I get this error when attempting to "Get Signatures" on a Contact entity in Dynamics CRM Online.

[This Guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ds-for-dynamics-online) was used to install DocuSign for Dynamics CRM.

It is a fresh install.  The DocuSign Config was created in CRM, successfully connecting to the DocuSign account.

This was all done while logged in with the Office 365 account that has the matching email address to the primary email address on the DocuSign account. DocuSign roles are assigned to the user within CRM.

The DocuSign password configuration is Custom, with zero security questions.

The DocuSign login being used is a DocuSign Admin. The DocuSign DS Admin Permission Set has "Allow view and manage envelope rights through API" and "Allow send on behalf of other users through API" checked.

The integration with SharePoint Online is installed and testing successfully.

The full error message is "Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): DocuSign.DocuSignRequest: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type DocuSign.DSREST.ValidateMemberAccountStatusResponse. Encountered unexpected character '<'."

Comment: It is unclear on page 9 of the documentation whether a DocuSign User must be added within CRM if the CRM user's email address matches the email address of the DocuSign user's.  I went ahead and added the User entry in CRM, but that did not resolve the problem.

Comment: you should contact DocuSign support

Comment: We have a DocuSign business plan, yet it does not include support for "advanced features".  That costs an additional $40 per month.

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say the client (Dynamics CRM Online) is sending a request to the DocuSign Service's API to validate our account status.  The API is returning an xml response message that does not match the schema the client expect.  So Dynamics throws an error when attempting to create (deserialize) the expected object from the API's xml response.

Comment: this kind of questions doesn't belong to stacoverflow, and you are having issues with a commercial product you are paying for, instead of guessing you need to contact DocuSign support or find a forum/community/group about DocuSign, check on LinkedIn or Facebook for example

Comment: Funny, I didn't think of this belonging on StackOverflow either.  DocuSign support steered me here, and there are some DocuSign tags.

Comment: DocuSign has their own forum, which I posted on initially.  I'll close this thread out with the results from there.